# How do I adjust my code to copy different ranges of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I recorded a macro that calculates using SUMIF and then autofills.

```
Range("H2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(RC[-5], ""10"", RC[-4])"
Range("H2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("H2:H3798")
Range("H2:H3798").Select
```

Is there a way to adjust the code so that it recognizes if the range is bigger or smaller than the "H2:H3798" range I used to make the macro? The data will always start at "H2" but will always have a different end range.

I tried to adjust it so it read "H2:H" & lastRow" but that led to a runtime error.

Comment: [this may be what you're looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Assuming you're finding the last row based on column A, `Dim lastRow As Long`, `lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`, `Range("H2:H" & lastRow).formulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(RC[-5], ""10"", RC[-4])"`